# Java - How to quit a While Loop mid loop

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to make a program that asks an electrician to enter a number in Volts. If he/she enters a value either bigger than `20` or less than `0`, the program should end without prompting the user to go again. Right now, I have it so it prompts the user to quit or continue, which I don't want. Here's the guts of the program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";
    int voltage;
    boolean Loop = true;

    while (Loop) {

        System.out.print("Enter a numeric value of 0 to 20 volts");
        input = kbReader.nextLine();
        voltage = Integer.parseInt(input);

        if (voltage < 0 || voltage > 20) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        }

        else if (voltage >= 0 && voltage < 5) {
            System.out.println("Insufficient Voltage - Replace Relay"); 
        }

        else if (voltage >= 5 && voltage < 15) {
            System.out.println("Low Voltage"); 
        }

        else if (voltage >= 15 && voltage < 18) {
            System.out.println("Voltage is in proper range");
        }
        else if (voltage >= 18 && voltage <= 20) {
            System.out.println("Voltage is high - Check Transformer"); 
        }

        System.out.print("\n\nType \"Q\" to quit, or type nothing to go again.");
        input = kbReader.nextLine();

        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            Loop = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The indentation seems to be a bit off. I'm not too sure how to fix that.

Comment: You've got two `input = kbReader.nextLine()` in your loop. That doesn't make sense!!! You should probably take the first one outside (before the beginning of) the loop. Alternatively, you can place the exit-condition immediately after the first input-scan, and get rid of the second input-scan.

Comment: Use a break keyword.

Comment: Looks like you should  replace 'System.out.println("invalid input");' with 'break;'

Comment: @AndyFedoroff only quotes should be in quotes, reverting your changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is

```
if (voltage < 0 || voltage > 20) {
    System.out.println("Invalid input.");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a break in that first if clause :

```
if (voltage < 0 || voltage > 20)
{
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a break;. Breaks allows the while loop to exit.